# Python: Enter or leave "User Perspective (local)"

Tags: python

I'm talking about the so-called User Local View, which you can enter by selecting an object and pressing "Numpad /".

I can detect an active "User Perspective":

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
   if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
      if area.spaces.active.local_view is not None:
          print("I'm in a user perspective")
```

That local view causes some quirks with several Python operations. Is there a way to **store** the current local view, **leave** it and **re-enter** it upon finish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the menu in the 3D view, and right-click the "View Global/Local" menu item. You can then choose "Copy Python Command". It'll give you `bpy.ops.view3d.localview()`, which is the operator that is executed when you click on that menu item.

Note that it does require a context of a 3D view, so if you try to execute that command as-is in the Python console, it'll refuse (your Python console doesn't have Global/Local view). However, if you execute it as part of your own operator running in a 3D view, it'll be fine. In that case you can also simply use `context.area.spaces.active.local_view` instead of iterating over all areas in the current screen.